# How to prevent to create the fake charge in the stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

I just make a website live and I'm using the stripe payment gateway. When we live the website, we just started receiving the fake charges of minimum amount and now these exist in thousand in our stripe account. Sometimes it is in decimal, US dollar, Euro
. Stripe has suspended our account 2 times. We don't know how we can prevent these charges and how they are doing. These charges are not created by us or our website. We've never proposed these kinds of amounts.
[image]

Stripe has recommended something to do like Radar rule, Rate limit, captcha, Restricted API. We've done everything, deleted the old secret key, and rolled it again, but as I mentioned above, these charges are not created by us. We're in live and stripe has suspended our account again but we don't know how we can prevent it.

Comment: That looks like card testing and you should follow the instructions provided by Stripe to mitigate it : https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention/card-testing

Comment: I have already done all the things that stripe has mentioned in this document but still receiving continuous.